# Equivariant Hilbert schemes of points

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hilbert-schemes

Let $G$ be a finite subgroup of $\mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{C})$ and let $X$ be the quotient surface $X = \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[x, y]^{G})$. Denote by $\mathrm{Hilb}^r([X])$ the equivariant Hilbert scheme on $\mathbb{C}^2$: the connected component of the $G$-fixed loci of $\mathrm{Hilb}^{rg}(\mathbb{C}^2)$ dominating $\mathrm{Sym}^r(X)$, where $g$ is the order of $G$. Write this map

$f: \mathrm{Hilb}^r([X]) \to \mathrm{Sym}^r(X)$.

(The case where $r = 1$ is the $G$-Hilbert scheme of Ito-Nakamura, and the map $f: G-\mathrm{Hilb}(\mathbb{C}^2) = \mathrm{Hilb}^1([X]) \to \mathrm{Sym}^1(X) = X$ is the crepant resolution.)

It would be great if someone can point out some literature in understanding this may $f$ in general. My specific question, might be known to the community is:

*Is the map $f$ semismall?*

Instead of taking $\mathrm{Hilb}^r([X])$ if one takes the usual Hilbert scheme of $r$ points on the smooth surface $G-\mathrm{Hilb}(\mathbb{C}^2)$ that would give a symplectic resolution of $\mathrm{Sym}^r(X)$. In particular, that is semismall. Maybe one can see that the map $f$ is also a symplectic resolution?

Thanks!

**This is a second part of the question, which I try to convince myself:**

Q: Is the zero-fiber, the pre-image of the 0-cycle of multiplicity $d$ supported at the singularity of $X$ a Lagrangian subvariety? (I don't think it is irreducible in general though.)

Thanks!

Comment: Assuming that the characteristic of $k$ does not divide the order of $G$, the $G$-invariant element $\beta = dx\wedge dy$ in $H^0(\mathbb{A}^2,\omega_{\mathbb{A}^2/k})$ induces an everywhere nondegenerate element $\beta_n$ on the Hilbert scheme $\text{Hilb}^{P_r}_{[\mathbb{A}^2/G],k}$, where $P$ is the Hilbert polynomial of $r$ times the $G$-representation $k[G]$.  Because $\text{Hilb}^{P_r}_{[\mathbb{A}^2/G],k}$ is smooth over $k$, it suffices to check that $\beta_r$ is nondegenerate at every codimension $1$ point, and this is the same computation as nondegeneracy of $\beta_1$.

Comment: @JasonStarr: Thanks! This is what I had in mind. But I am not comfortable to say that $\beta = dx \wedge dy$ is $G$-invariant, since it is only so up to a scalar multiple.

Comment: "But I am not comfortable to say that $\beta = dx \wedge dy$ is $G$-invariant, since it is only so up to a scalar multiple."  If $G$ is a subgroup of $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$, then $G$ preserves $\beta$.

Comment: @JasonStarr: Can I say that the form $\beta_r$ is restricted from the one on $\mathrm{Hilb}^{rg}(\mathbb{A}^2)$ onto this $G$-invariant smooth subvariety?

Comment: "Can I say ..."  Yes, for a finite quotient stack such as $[\mathbb{A}^2/G]$, you can construct $\beta_r$ in that way (up to dividing through by an integer).  For a smooth, $2$-dimensional Deligne-Mumford stack with Gorenstein coarse moduli space that is not necessarily a finite quotient stack, it is better to use traces of $p$-forms as in my article with de Jong about rational curves on cubic threefolds.

Comment: Please note: even if $G$ is not in $\textbf{SL}_2(\mathbb{C})$, you can still restrict the $2$-form from $\text{Hilb}^{rg}(\mathbb{A}^2)$ to the $G$-invariant locus.  However, "averaging over an orbit" will sum up over powers of a non-identity root of unity, and that sum will equal zero.  So when $G$ is not contained in $\textbf{SL}_2(\mathbb{C})$, the restricted $2$-form will be identically zero.